# Comparing 3 bits and sending a 1 bit output

Tags: assembly, 8051

For a question we were required to compare three bits of two ports and then use three bits of another port as output. If the three bits stored in the first port are equal to the three bits in the second port then the first bit of the output is set to 1. If it is greater then p2.1 is set high. If it is less than p2.2 is set high. My question is that it is possible to solve this problem in this way as well as using gates (and/or but that would require bit by bit which is a pain). Is there an easier way?

```
ORG 000H
MOV A, P1; x is p1 and y is p3
MOV R5, P3;
MOV P2, #0;
CJNE A,05H, CHECK; if it isn't equal we go to check routine
SETB P2.0; Equal output set high
SJMP HERE; End progam
CHECK: 
MOV A, P1
SUBB A, P3 ; Subtract
JC HM; 
SETB P2.1; 
SJMP HERE;
HM: SETB P2.2; 
SJMP HERE; 

HERE: CLR A;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare only three bits from a port you first need to mask off the other bits otherwise you'll be comparing all eight bits. Then you only need to use a single comparison, whether with SUBB or CJNE, to determine if the the bits from one port are equal to, less than, or greater than the other. Both instructions subtract their two operands and set the carry flag (C) according to the result. If they're equal then SUBB stores 0 in A and you can test this with JZ/JNZ. In the case of CJNE the instruction doesn't jump if they're equal. In either case when they're not equal you can test the carry flag with JC/JNC to determine if they're less than or greater than. If the A register is less than the other operand then these instructions set the carry flag.

If you use SUBB don't forget that this instruction, "Subtract with Borrow", uses the carry flag as an input. This means you need to clear the carry flag (CLR C) before using it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set an output register to 1 (assuming that it's going to be equal). Call this R.
2. Compare the two ports.
3. Branch if equal to 7 - done.
4. Branch if carry to 6 - greater
5. Shift R left 1 bit
6. Shift R left 1 bit
7. Store R in P2

This drop through logic is integral to assembler programming.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by shifting? It has not been covered in class.

Comment: Which chip are you using? 8051?

Comment: Yes, an 8051 microcontroller.

Comment: In that case, R (in the above example) is the accumulator and the command is RL 1 (rotate left 1 bit without carry). So binary %001 becomes %010 becomes %100. Mathematically, it's a fantastically fast way of doubling the number. The 1 can be any number from 0 to 6 - not relevant to this problem but it will come in useful later on.

Comment: @NyxStars: left shift is equivalent to adding a number to itself.  @ Mike: Can you eliminate the 2nd branch by using `adc`?  If there's a carry from the 2nd compare, `1+1` is the same as `1 << 1`.  That probably doesn't save any code size, though, since apparently 8051 has a compare-and-branch instruction.

Comment: @Peter. Risc machines (like the 8051) have one instruction per cycle but for any other architecture, ADC is much slower than shifting and has a shorter instruction (no or short operand) so it's generally better to use it. Plus, I wanted to illustrate fall-through code which is rare in other languages other than the occasional case-without-a-break.

Comment: @Mike: Yeah, the overall point of illustrating good branch layout is a good one.  I'm used to modern x86 CPUs where jumps are expensive :P.  On x86, `adc` is slightly more expensive than `add` on Intel microarchitectures before Broadwell.  Single uop on Broadwell/Skylake (taking advantage of 3-dependency uops introduced in Haswell for FMA).  It's always been 1 m-op on AMD. Anyway, on x86, `adc` might be an interesting way to save code-size and uops.  (`cmp`/`jcc` can macro-fuse into a single uop, but only one macro-fusion per decode group...).  Anyway, a bit different from 8051 :P

Comment: This problem with this is that R has to be accumulator A and but A also needs to used as a register in steps 2 and 3. So you need to load A after these steps, but it's too late for the equal case. So now it actually hurts because you're only eliminating one branch but have extra load and shift instructions. Also 8051 isn't RISC, the instructions vary in length and instructions can take 1, 2 and in a couple of cases even 4 cycles to execute. And that's only true because the 8051 defines 1 machine cycle as 12 bus cycles. Really these are 12, 24 and 48 cycle instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that accept three arbitrary bits from each input port.

I assume the following:

Set P2.0 if P0 = P1

Set P2.1 if P0 > P1

Set P2.1 else

```
    org    0000H
Init:
    MOV     P2DIR, 00H             ; Make P2 an output

ReadAndMask:
    MOV     A,     P0              ; read port P0
    ANL     A,     #13H            ; your P1-mask
    MOV     R0,    A               ; Save in R0

    MOV     A,     P1              ; read port P1
    ANL     A,     #0A1H           ; your P1-mask

    CJNE    A,     00H,    NotEq   ; compare A with R0

Equal:
    MOV     P2,    #01H            ; Set P2.0 clear the rest
    SJMP    ReadAndMask            ; Repeat forever

NotEq:
    JC      P0Greater              ; Check carry to see if P0 > P1

P0Greater:
    MOV     P2,    #02H            ; Set P2.1 clear the rest
    SJMP    ReadAndMask            ; Repeat forever

P0NotGreater:
    MOV     P2,    #04H            ; Set P2.2 clear the rest
    SJMP    ReadAndMask            ; Repeat forever

    end
```

Comment: You need to shift one of the sets of bits over to match the alignment of the other set of bits before doing the comparison.